# Input string was not in correct format when reading ints from a file into an array

Tags: c#

I am getting the error "Input string was not in correct format" when counter is equal to 2. In other words, when I am trying to put the value into resourceTypes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Banking_Steven_Smathers
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int processes=0;
        public static int resourceTypes=0;
        public static int [,] allocation=new int[3,5];
        public static int[,] max=new int[3,5];
        public static int[,] need=new int[3,5];
        public static int[] available=new int[3];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            readFile();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void readFile()
        {
            StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader("data.txt");
            int counter=0;
            while (counter <= 1)
            {
                processes = int.Parse(fileReader.ReadLine());
                counter++;
            }
            while(counter<=2)
            {
                resourceTypes = int.Parse(fileReader.ReadLine());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the text file I'm trying to read from:

```
5
3
10 5 7
0 1 0
2 0 0
3 0 2
2 1 1
0 0 2
7 5 3
3 2 2
9 0 2
2 2 2
4 3 3
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read about `Split`

Comment: The third line has spaces in between the numbers and as such can't be parsed as an int.

Comment: Replace your reading code as `var line = fileReader.ReadLine(); processes = int.Parse(line);` and the debug code line by line https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I advise you to start looking at signatures and documentation of methods.`int.Parse(string)` does do what you think it does.

Answer (score -2):

You can reproduce the same error with the following much simpler (but also buggy) code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = int.Parse("10 5 7");
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Basically the int.Parse method doesn't know how to convert "10 5 7" into an integer... which is fair enough since it looks like 3 separate integers (maybe you expected it to come back with the answer 1057... but you'll have to remove the spaces if you want it to do that).

Comment: What's with the down vote? This is exactly why the original code is throwing an error (and without any further context for what the OP actually wants to do, it's hard to provide any more useful information on what the code should look like).